# How do I add up values for columns based on repeating row column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, repeat

I have a table of values that I am selecting from the database using sql.

```
SELECT

  a.Chapter, a.price, b.book

FROM 

  Table1 a, Table2 b, Table3 c

WHERE

  a.id = c.id and b.id = c.id2

GROUP BY

  a.Chapter, a.price

ORDER BY

  a.Chapter
```

The values it brings back are:

```
|Chapter|Price|book|
|_______|_____|____|
|01     | 25  |eg1 |
|01     | 23  |eg2 |
|01     | 9   |eg3 |
|02     | 15  |eg4 |
|02     | 89  |eg5 |
|02     | 11  |eg6 |
|02     | 3   |eg7 |
|02     | 25  |eg8 |
```

How do I take the prices of every repeating 01 (Which is in string format btw because it's not the chapter of a book) and add them together and make them the new price? For example:

```
Chapter   Price
   01      57   
   02      143
```

> The book part isn't really important at the moment so it can be excluded

Comment: Who taught you this kind of joins? They were made redundant in **1992** and should no longer be used. Use proper joins instead: `from books b join chapters c on c.book_id = b.book_id`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma THANK YOU!!! That worked like a charm

Comment: As to your query: It is invalid as mentioned in my answer. MySQL let's this slip. You may want to set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode as long as you are insecure on group by aggregations.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes I will do that right now thank you for the suggestion and help

Comment: One more thing: It doesn't help anonymizing table and column names to this extent. It just makes the query harder to read for us. It seems table1 is a chapter table, table2 the related book table and table3?, well ... Then a column called ID should be the table's ID. You'd rather join on book_id and whatever. Please consider this next time you write a request :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong. You group by chapter and price, but you also select the book. This book will be one of the books matching the chapter and price arbitrarily chosen. So with this data

```
book chapter price
eg1  01      25
eg1  02      30
eg2  01      25
eg3  01      30
```

you might get

```
book chapter price
eg1  01      25
eg1  02      30
eg3  01      30
```

thus surpressing book eg2.

Anyway, you get a result row per chapter with `GROUP BY chapter`. You get a sum with `SUM`.

```
select chapter, sum(price)
from chapters
group by chapter;
order by chapter;
```

Comment: I see I see... thank you... I did as you suggested and it worked... Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DISTINCT?

```
SELECT DISTINCT x
from table1
where example = example2
```

Comment: think i get what you r saying andyes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Chapter, sum(a.price)
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table3 c on c.id = a.id
INNER JOIN Table2 b on b.id = c.id
GROUP BY
  a.Chapter
ORDER BY
  a.Chapter
```

Comment: both inner joins are useless in this case, he already have a selected answer.

Comment: Edit your answer and explain to the community, not to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

It can achieve with one table only

```
SELECT
  a.Chapter, SUM(a.price) as price
FROM 
  Table1 a
GROUP BY
  a.Chapter
ORDER BY
  a.Chapter
```